# Emacs: most used directory highlighted with a background color

Tags: emacs, highlighting, dired

I'd like to have the most used (or default) directory highlighted with a background color while I'm using Dired mode in Emacs. I know that highlighting works with the [hl-line library](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightCurrentLine) for current line but unfortunatly I don't know the lisp language very well. I would be interested to know if it is also possible with Dired mode too.

Comment: It sure is possible, but I don't know of any package that does it out of the box. First, you will need to define what you mean with "most used directory" -- is it the directory that contains most open buffers? Once there, you can add a font-lock rule that highlights the line that contains that name.

Comment: I agree with @Lindydancer: your question is not very clear. Where do you see directories listed in Dired, of which you want to highlight the "most used"? Are you talking about highlighting the parent-directory portion of the header of an inserted subdirectory?